# Convert currency to decimal in PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, currency

I'm looking for the shortest/easiest way to achieve this.

`var savings = <?php echo $list_price ?> - discount_price;`

`savings: 1.00`

`$list_price: '$10.00';`
`discount_price: '$9.00';`

Cheers.

Comment: Give some examples of inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: @Cal Jacobson Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var savings = parseFloat('<?php echo $list_price ?>'.substr(1)) -
  parseFloat(discount_price.substr(1));
```

This parses the string as a number, skipping the first characters (dollar).

Comment: Shouldn't `parseInt` be `parseFloat`?  What if `$list_price` was $12.56?

Comment: Rocket, of course! I'm used to `parseInt`, and typed it in wrongly :|

Answer (score 0):

isnt currency by default represented as a "decimal" (of sorts)

```
$1.00 = 1.00
0.50c = 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the answer?

```
var savings = parseFloat(<?php echo $list_price ?>) - discount_price;
```